# How does the body determine where to deposit fat reserves?

Tags: human-biology, fat-metabolism

People's bodies store fat in similar areas, but often there are subtle differences in which areas are first or slightly more effected. This seems to also be apparent with morbidity, where certain areas are overburdened with adipose while other areas are less effected. What are the factors the determine which areas exhibit build up, while others do not?